# Si una columna incluye # en su nombre, como hago el Select sin que me detecte como comentario?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como les decia, necesito evitar que me detecte como comentario ya que la columna se llama T#

```
select * from ventas.envios where T# = 'T1'
```

Comment: No es cuestión mia, el profesor es muy exigente con la rubrica

Comment: ok listo, mushisimas gracias.

Comment: Recuerda agregar como texto el còdigo y las consultas, ayuda mucho a que la comunidad pueda ayudarte de una mejor forma,  saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando los nombres de:

- Columnas
- Tablas

Incluyen nombres con palabras reservadas o en este caso el símbolo para comentar debes usar *backticks* para que no sea interpretado de forma literal.

Quedando por ejemplo así:

```
SELECT `algo` FROM tuTabla;
```

**REFERENCIAS**

- [Uso de backticks en sentencias](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de **MySql** puedes usar los backticks como contenedores para indicar el campo

```
  select * from ventas.envios where `T#` = 'T1'
```

En el caso de **Sqlite** tienes que usar como contenedores en el query para el campo `[` y `]`, de esta forma podràs hacer referencia al campo sin que sea tomado como comentario.

Por ejemplo si el nombre de tu campo es T# , debes hacer referencia a el como [T#] en tu query, de esta forma:

```
select * from ventas.envios where [T#] = 'T1'
```